# Civilization 5, Civilizations wont show

Tags: xml

I'm working on a civilization mod, and this is the first civilization I actually made for this mod, following the tables at the top of each xml file. 
I have made one civilization before, but this one doesn't seem to work, or at least not show up in game. I couldn't find any posts on this from before, so answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<GameData>
    <Leaders>
        <Row>
            <ID>0</ID>
            <Type>LEADER_XIAO</Type>
            <Description>Xiao</Description>
            <Civilopedia>TXT_KEY_LEADER_ALEXANDER_PEDIA</Civilopedia>
            <CivilopediaTag>TXT_KEY_CIVILOPEDIA_LEADERS_ALEXANDER</CivilopediaTag>
            <ArtDefineTag>Alexander_Scene.xml</ArtDefineTag>
            <VictoryCompetitiveness>8</VictoryCompetitiveness>
            <WonderCompetitiveness>7</WonderCompetitiveness>
            <MinorCivCompetitiveness>3</MinorCivCompetitiveness>
            <AIPlayable>false</AIPlayable>
            <Boldness>8</Boldness>
            <DiploBalance>3</DiploBalance>
            <WarmongerHate>2</WarmongerHate>
            <DenounceWillingness>7</DenounceWillingness>
            <DoFWillingness>4</DoFWillingness>
            <Loyalty>4</Loyalty>
            <Neediness>4</Neediness>
            <Forgiveness>5</Forgiveness>
            <Chattiness>7</Chattiness>
            <Meanness>7</Meanness>
            <PortraitIndex>9</PortraitIndex>
            <IconAtlas>LEADER_ATLAS</IconAtlas>
        </Row>

    </Leaders>
    <Leader_MajorCivApproachBiases>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_WAR</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>6</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_HOSTILE</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>7</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_DECEPTIVE</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>4</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_GUARDED</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>5</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_AFRAID</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>3</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_FRIENDLY</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>5</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MajorCivApproachType>MAJOR_CIV_APPROACH_NEUTRAL</MajorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>4</Bias>
        </Row>
    </Leader_MajorCivApproachBiases>
    <Leader_MinorCivApproachBiases>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MinorCivApproachType>MINOR_CIV_APPROACH_IGNORE</MinorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>4</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MinorCivApproachType>MINOR_CIV_APPROACH_FRIENDLY</MinorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>5</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MinorCivApproachType>MINOR_CIV_APPROACH_PROTECTIVE</MinorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>8</Bias>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <MinorCivApproachType>MINOR_CIV_APPROACH_CONQUEST</MinorCivApproachType>
            <Bias>4</Bias>
        </Row>
    </Leader_MinorCivApproachBiases>
    <Leader_Flavors>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_OFFENSE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>8</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_DEFENSE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_CITY_DEFENSE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_MILITARY_TRAINING</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_RECON</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_RANGED</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>3</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_MOBILE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>8</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_NAVAL</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_NAVAL_RECON</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_NAVAL_GROWTH</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_NAVAL_TILE_IMPROVEMENT</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_AIR</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>3</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_EXPANSION</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>8</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_GROWTH</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>4</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_TILE_IMPROVEMENT</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>4</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_INFRASTRUCTURE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>4</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_PRODUCTION</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_GOLD</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>3</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_SCIENCE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_CULTURE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>7</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_HAPPINESS</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_GREAT_PEOPLE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_WONDER</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_RELIGION</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>5</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_DIPLOMACY</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>9</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_SPACESHIP</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>7</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_WATER_CONNECTION</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>6</Flavor>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <FlavorType>FLAVOR_NUKE</FlavorType>
            <Flavor>7</Flavor>
        </Row>
    </Leader_Flavors>
    <Leader_Traits>
        <Row>
            <LeaderType>LEADER_XIAO</LeaderType>
            <TraitType>TRAIT_CITY_STATE_FRIENDSHIP</TraitType>
        </Row>
    </Leader_Traits>  
</GameData>
```

Comment: Does the xml file require the xml identification line : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

Comment: @jdweng Its aldready there, i just forgot to paste it, sorry.